# inserting a node into a tree in python

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, tree, append

I am trying to write a node class to create a tree structure. There seems to be
some problem when I'm trying to add a child node to the root node with the method "addChild" because the child node appears to have itself in its children list. I couldn't figure out why, so any help is appreciated.

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, x, y, children = []):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def addChild(self): 
        b=node('b', 5, 5)
        self.children.append(b)
        return

root=node('a',0.,0.)
print root.children 

root.addChild() 

print root.children
print root.children[0].children
```

Yields:

```
[<__main__.node object at 0x7faca9f93e50>]
[<__main__.node object at 0x7faca9f93e50>]
```

Whereas the second "print" line should have returned an empty array.

Comment: Every node is referencing the same list. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default parameter value `children = []` assigns a single list object to the `__init__` function that is then used on every call all children. [This is a common mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument). Instead, create `children` in the `__init__` function itself:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, x, y, children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = [] if children is None else children
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
 # ...
```